# aspnet Membership Database to store extra employee attributes

Tags: asp.net

I'm using aspnet memberhips database for authorization and authentication for my azure web application.

This aspnet application contains the employees details. All good until we got new requirment. The new requirement is to in include lots of extra attributes related to employees such as awardcode, costcentre, division, location etc...

The requirement is also to admin these details via Admin portal.

Is there any way we can fit the above requirement with in aspnet database? Should I add extra tables and fields or there's a better way of acheving this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the ASP.NET Profile provider. It's another component of the Membership framework. It stores a somewhat dynamic list of user properties in the database, typically in the aspnet_Profile table. You can get a lot of functionality for free by making additions to Web.config, or you can customize heavily by implementing a custom profile provider. Here are some links to get started:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163457.aspx

There have been times though when this approach wasn't a great fit for me, so I simply created a separate UserRecord table in the database with exactly the columns I wanted, and added some views to the database that joined UserRecord with the bulitin aspnet_Membership table, etc., to get the right combination of data.

Comment: Thanks @esker, when you say you created a separate UserRecord Table. How did you manage this custom table. e.g. when registering user I want these fields to appear on Admin page.

Comment: For something like displaying a list of users in an admin page, I just wrote a lot of code to manually retrieve the user records via Linq to SQL, and looped over the list of records retrieved to output the information in an aspx file. No direct usage of ASP.NET Membership provider classes for this case. I created a view in SQL Server that combined the custom UserRecord table with aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Roles, aspnet_Users, etc., to get the right combination of columns for each user and simplify the Linq statement.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like you had to write your own membership admin page with out using asp membership AIPs or http://mywsat.codeplex.com/