# Best practice to store extra data for users in a SL business application + ASP.NET authentication scenario?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services

I'm about to write a Silverlight business application and I'm planning to use the ASP.NET built in authentication service (from what I read it's safe enough).

My problem is I already have a database with a `Users` table which has many more columns than the one in the ASP.NET DB.

What's the best practice, here?

**Option 1:** Add columns to the ASP.NET `Users` table.

**Option 2:** Only put in my `Users` table the columns which are not in the ASP.NET `Users` table.

**Option 3:** Use the `Profile` table from the ASP.NET DB to store my users' extra data.

**Option 4:** You name it. ;o)

I currently tend towards option 2 because I think altering the ASP.NET DB would restrict the use of this DB to this very application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is probably pretty good (you can override and customise the membership provider classes to make this a bit more seamless for you).

The profile table is useful, as it is very easy to add to, but can be a real pain to query directly (e.g. creating a gridview showing the firstname and lastname of all your users, where this data is all in one column in the profile).

Comment: Thanks. I eventually found this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811737/aspnet-membership-database-to-store-extra-employee-attributes) where the answerer used a `RecordUser` table and created a view to join this table and the one in aspnetdb. I think I'll go this way, then.